# How to convert Scala UDF's to Java version in Apache Spark?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions, apache-spark-sql

I've written apache spark udf in scala like this:

```
val toLongDate = udf((t: String) => new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss aa").parse(t).getTime)
```

I want to write this udf in java like this:

```
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf;

UserDefinedFunction toLongDate = udf(myFunction1, typeTag1, typeTage2);
```

[image]

I don't know how to provide these argument to `org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf` function?

I've write myFunction1 but the IntelliJ Idea show me the error than can not resolve `compose` and `andThen` functions:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you can't get a `TypeTag` from Java in any meaningful way, it's intended to be generated by the Scala compiler. You'd have to compile some Scala code producing the `TypeTag`s, in which case it's much easier to call `udf` from there instead.

For `Function1` the answer is to extend `AbstractFunction1`:

```
new AbstractFunction1<String, Long>() {
    @Override
    Long apply(String x) { ... }
}
```